# Detox tests on iPad without the simulator

Tags: react-native, detox

I have a react native app & a couple of detox test cases for it. I am trying to run these detox tests on iPad without the simulator. Wanted to know if it is possible, if yes then which version of detox supports this. Otherwise is there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: No, not yet.

There is an open issue for this, and some users have found a way to do it, find it here: https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/95

This comment explains the details on how to get it to work: https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/95#issuecomment-448365050